# Automatically populate field after insert data

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I want import data from excel to custom module.
I have start and finish (datetime) in excel is it possible define field total (finish - start) to get result after import data?

For example:

```
class time(models.Model):
    _name = "time"
    _description = "Time"

    start = fields.Datetime(string = 'Start', placeholder="Start") 
    finish = fields.Datetime(string='Finish', placeholder="Finish")


    total = fields.Float(string='Total minutes', placeholder="Total")


_defaults = {

                 'total': (finish - start)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add onchange method of `start` and `finish` to compute `total`.

Ex.

```
@api.onchange('start', 'finish')
def onchange_start_finish(self):
    for time in self:
        time.total = time.finish - time.start
```

Other way,

if you take a compute field as total.like,

```
total = fields.Float(compute='_methods_total', string='Total minutes', placeholder="Total")

@api.depends('start', 'finish')
def _methods_total(self):
    for time in self:
        time.total = time.finish - time.start
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'bool' and 'unicode',